# Prove this is not a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

If $$ x_{n}:= \sqrt{n}$$ show that$$ x_{n}$$ satisfies $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|=0 $$ but that it is not a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: The sequence is on $\Bbb R$, so if it were Cauchy, then it must converge. But we can see that it clear does not.

Comment: @Nameless It is not *clear* to the OP, so why say it is **clear**?

Comment: Summer, the next time you ask a question on this site, I, (and I assume some fragment of the math stack exchange community), would appreciate it if you would include some of your ideas about the problem that you are soliciting help for. This, in effect, helps improve the overall quality of the website and furthermore, helps us help you quickly and more efficiently.

Comment: Thank you Rustyn, I did have ideas, but I am not used to this way of typing. Today I just figure out how to type questions, I will try to type my own answer next time =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$|x_{n+1}-x_n|=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

But since $\;\sqrt n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty\;$  the sequence doesn't converge *finitely*, which is a necessary and sufficient condition for a sequence to be Cauchy..

Comment: Very succinct answer. +1

Comment: You should probably say that, in this context, a sequence is Cauchy if and only if it converges. That is what you are really saying in your second line. (Sorry it's just my opinion, and you needn't change anything if you don't want to).

Comment: Thanks @Rustyn, I shall add that for clearity.